# Alternative location to store tmp files on linux

Tags: linux, scripting, python, compilation, noexec

So I have a python script that I compile with `pyinstaller` to a single file. at the time of running, by default, the script will unbundle the modules in `/tmp/` also [you can change the default TMPDIR at the time of compilation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html?highlight=tmp#operation-not-permitted-error).

**PROBLEM**:
As you might know, this is a common security practice that you mount `/tmp/` or `/var/tmp/` as a `noexec`. the problem is that my script can't execute the modules from `/tmp/` or `/var/tmp/` on some of my client's servers.

**QUESTION**:
I want to change my scripts TMPDIR to somewhere else to prevent this problem, where is the standard location for something like this?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841334/using-an-alternate-tmp-location-with-pyinstaller/53418707#53418707

Comment: why not using the source folders? since the tmpdir can be verified for can execute oflr not,i would then just use a small if else and create a folder dll,do the job and remove it.